# Doctrine2: query using NativeQuery and ResultSetMapping

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have this bit of code in a custom repository symfony 2 class, I'm struggling to understand why $results is always empty.
MyApplicationBundle:Archive is an entity class mapped to the DB
collection is a join table (ManyToMany) not an entity
present is not a property of this class but I need it in the result
$where_str is built above
what am I doing wrong? thanks

```
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('MyApplicationBundle:Archive', 'a');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'id', 'id');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'author', 'author');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'title', 'title');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'present', 'present');

    $sql = "select
              a.id,
              a.author,
              a.title,
              IF((select c.archive_id from collection c where c.archive_id = a.id and c.user_id = :user),1,0) as present
            from
              archive a
            where
              $where_str";

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
    $query->setParameters($arrParameters);

    $results = $query->getResult();

    return $results;
```

more than happy to try using DQL or DQB if better.

Answer (score 0):

after some attempt I found out the bit of code above is correct. I just needed to add the field "present" in the Archive entity, create getter and setter (doctrine:generate:entities) and to update the DB to create the field in the table (doctrine:schema:update --force). no matter if you are not going to use it anywhere else.